# Monkey patch the module that imports this one

Tags: python, python-3.x, monkeypatching

So, I have a Python application that has this functionality where any module-like file in the `extensions` subdirectory of the program directory gets imported at some early point in the application's initialization process.

This looks something like this (assume this is `my_application.py`):

```
def do_init():
    for thefname in glob.iglob(os.path.join(".","extensions","*")):
        SourceFileLoader(os.path.basename(thefname),thefname).load_module()
    #do other init stuff...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    do_init()
    do_cool_things()
```

Now, I'd like to be able to have a .py file in that extensions directory that goes something like this:

```
import my_application
def my_cool_things():
    print("The original things have been overridden.")
my_application.do_cool_things = my_cool_things
```

And this works... for future imports of `my_application`. But the `do_cool_things` call inside the `if __name__ == "__main__"` guard exhibits the original behavior. Why is this happening and how can I make that call exhibit the modified behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module created by running a script called `my_application.py` surprisingly isn't `my_application`. The module created by running a script is `__main__`. Of course, the module created by *importing* a file called `my_application.py` would be called `my_application`.

Two solutions to your problem are to replace `import my_application` with either `import __main__` or `import builtins`.

Simple demonstration:

```
#x.py
import y
print ("Hello", hello)
```

and

```
#y.py
import __main__
__main__.hello = 'world'
```

Test on Ubuntu 14.04 with Python 3.4.3:

```
$ python3 x.py
Hello world
$
```

Comment: This works! And here I am trying to get at the module's functions by unwinding the stack up through the import machinery... :P